# Interval Arithmetic Library: boost::numeric::interval in C++

Tags: c++, math, boost, intervals

I searched Stack Exchange and the web in general, including the boost instructions page but i still have some problems so i hope someone with more knowledge can help me out.

I need to compute unions and intersections of closed, open and half open intervals ideally of type double or float. In my search i found the boost library mentioned in the title.

Their hull function is not a true union (they state that on the instruction page), but there also is no clear replacement for it and the hull is just not enough as a union replacement. This combined with it only being able to work with closed intervals makes it a rather sub-par choice but i couldnt find anything else. (If you know of any library that can do what i need, please tell me :)

In terms of this library i have encountered a few problems that i cant seem to solve on my own or find any explanation online for.

By default it throws an exception and aborts if a function returns an empty interval, for example using their intersection function for two intervals with no intersection (as shown in the code below), there seems to be a way to configure the policy class to return a replacement value and basically work normally with NaN and empty intervals but i couldnt make this work so far, due to my limited knowledge with external libraries like this.

Below i listed some simple code example im currently stuck at, because i cant figure out how to use or change the policy class to work with empty intervals.

I read the instruction, checker and policy page up and down but my knowledge doesnt seem to be enough to make this work. So i appreciate any help you can provide.

```
typedef boost::numeric::interval<double> I;
double inf = numeric_limits<double>::infinity();

I a(2,5);
cout << "a[" << boost::numeric::lower(a) << ", " << boost::numeric::upper(a) << "]\n";
I b(3,9);
cout << "b[" << boost::numeric::lower(b) << ", " << boost::numeric::upper(b) << "]\n";
I c(6,7);
cout << "b[" << boost::numeric::lower(c) << ", " << boost::numeric::upper(c) << "]\n";

cout << "Union a | b: " << "[" << boost::numeric::lower(boost::numeric::intersect(a, b)) << ", " << boost::numeric::upper(boost::numeric::intersect(a, b)) << "]\n";
// correctly lists [3,6] as intersection
cout << "Union a | c: " << "[" << boost::numeric::lower(boost::numeric::intersect(a, c)) << ", " << boost::numeric::upper(boost::numeric::intersect(a, c)) << "]\n";
// throws error due to empty interval being returned and not having lower or upper
```

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you might be after a library that is not geared to numeric computation. Boost has ICL (Interval container Library) as well.

It has interval sets/maps, which work with discrete or continuous, bounded or unbounded intervals.

It has various combining behaviours (joining adjacent intervals, splitting intervals on boundaries, etc. including custom combiners).

It has various collection/aggregating strategies for co-domains when mapping (e.g. quantifiers when the mapped values are numeric, or collectors when the map values are sets).

Here's a simple starter. (Note I did not replicate your exact input to show the various open/closed and default interval types).

> Note also that output serialization seems to be a breeze in comparison.

This is only just grazing the surface so

- per-use the [documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/icl/doc/html/boost_icl/examples/interval.html)
- see various examples to be found [on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A85371+%5Bboost-icl%5D)

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/309e66eca87a272b)**

```
#include <boost/icl/interval.hpp>
#include <boost/icl/interval_set.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace icl = boost::icl;

using S = icl::interval_set<double>;
using I = S::interval_type;
constexpr inline auto inf = std::numeric_limits<I::domain_type>::infinity();

int main() {
    I const
        a = I::closed(2,5),
        b(3,9),
        c = I::left_open(6,7);

#define INSPECT(expr) std::cout << #expr << ": " << (expr) << "\n";
    INSPECT(a);
    INSPECT(b);
    INSPECT(c);

    INSPECT(hull(a,b));
    INSPECT(S{a} | b);
    INSPECT(S{a} & b);
    INSPECT(S{a} & c);

    INSPECT(S{a} | b | c);
    // potentially more efficient:
    INSPECT([=] { S s; for (auto i:{a,b,c}) s.insert(i); return s;}());

    INSPECT(S{a} - (S{b} | c));
    INSPECT(S{a} & (S{b} | c));
}
```

Prints

```
a: [2,5]
b: [3,9)
c: (6,7]
hull(a,b): [2,9)
S{a} | b: {[2,9)}
S{a} & b: {[3,5]}
S{a} & c: {}
S{a} | b | c: {[2,9)}
[=] { S s; for (auto i:{a,b,c}) s.insert(i); return s;}(): {[2,9)}
S{a} - (S{b} | c): {[2,3)}
S{a} & (S{b} | c): {[3,5]}
```

Comment: Note that I focused on the functionality you were after. If you find that you need computation as well, there's no reason why you can't use both libraries of course

Comment: Thanks, i found the ICL but also had some troubles with that and especially combining both libraries, but your example really helped!

I think using the ICL library makes more sense than to use the Numeric one for what i need.

Thanks again!